# Listing Result by Date - showing at 8am - not midnight

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm having a bit of a brain fart... Listing results of available slots by date.  And it is set for showing a week ahead...  But I'd like it to show the last result after 8am in the morning, rather than at midnight each night...  Is there a way to do that?

This code below works fine for displaying the results, just shows it at midnight each night - and I'd like it to show the next result at 8am...

```
    <cfset datelist = #DateAdd("d", tydef.numdays, todaydate)#>

   <cfquery name="list" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from shindates
    where sdate >= #createODBCDate(todaydate)# 
    and stime >= #createODBCDateTime(timehr)# 
    and sdate <= #createODBCDateTime(datelist)# 
    and typeid = '#ty.typeid#'
    order by sdate, stime
   </cfquery>
```

K - I think I have it sorted using a cfif and cutting off last day - then searching for last day by itself when it is after 9am - works... But if anyone has any code cleanup suggestions - I'll take them...

This works below

```
   <cfset datelist = #DateAdd("d", tydef.numdays, todaydate)#>

   <cfset sdatelist = #DateAdd("d", -1, datelist)#>

   <cfset stime = CreateTime(9,0,0)>

   <cfquery name="shinny" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from shindates
    where sdate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#todaydate#">
    and stime >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#timehr#">
    and sdate <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#sdatelist#"> 
    and typeid = '#ty.typeid#'
    order by sdate, stime
   </cfquery>

   <cfif #DatePart("h", timenow)# GTE #DatePart("h", stime)#>

   <cfquery name="lastday" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from shindates
    where sdate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#datelist#">
    and sdate <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#datelist#"> 
    and typeid = '#ty.typeid#'
    order by sdate, stime
    </cfquery>

    </cfif>
```

Comment: What are the values of the three variables?

Comment: And what's the data type of the relevant columns? And what DB are you using? You should also parameterise that SQL instead of hardcoding your values into your statement. And are you really using ODBC still?

Comment: Todaydate - is date today, timehr is today time (current hour) and datelist - is the added amount of days desired (7) - so it searches for anything after todays date, after the hour (does not show expired ones) and for the next 7 days... But I want the very last one showing after 8am - and not at midnight

Comment: The description of the issue is still a little confusing... It would help to post a small data dump. ie What is a sample of the *actual* date/time's in the query, and what were you *expecting* instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cutting off the datelist above on my edited post above - I was able to accomplish this.

Basically I pull the week - cut off the last date.

Display the week exclusing the last day.  And then after 9am - display the last day with a simple cfif statement on the 9am.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is:

```
and stime >= #createODBCDateTime(timehr)#
```

CreateODBCDateTime() creates a datetime object.  If you simply supply it a time, it will use the current date.

The solution is to use proper datatypes.  I assume you already did something like this:

```
<cfset stime = CreateTime(8,0,0)>
```

That being the case, you want this in your query.

```
 and stime >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#stime#">
```

For a variety of reasons, you want to use query parameters for every variable in your query.  This will eliminate the need to use CreateODBCDateTime().

Comment: Thx - but - that just sets a time of 8am which it then searches for after 8am... The timehr is doing the same thing based on current time... What I am trying to do - is not list that last result until after 8am... But all other results show...  Basically at midnight - it shows the next result... Complaint is coming - that people can't sign up at midnight - and want that result shown at 8am next morning - not midnight...

Comment: What I'm thinking is - I could minus 1 day - and search for 6days and show the 6days - and then do a cfif after 8am search for results on the 7th day

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  You will have to do some conditional logic based on Hour(now()).